# Codeigniter Validation for Multidimensional Array Data

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I having a problem to validate multiple row data in Codeigniter by using form validation. Below code are ok to validate the 1st row of data. The subsequent row data i added via javascript was not able to validate. After i clicked submit, the next row that i disappeared. Anyone can help to this?

Appreciate and thanks in advance for any help.

HTML

```
  <!-- Form -->
  <?php echo form_open(base_url('air'), array('class'=> 'form-horizontal','id'=> 'calc_form')) ?>
 <table>
 <tbody id="item-row">
 <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="load[1][grossweight]" value="<? =set_value('load[1][grossweight]')?>" placeholder="Gross Weight" >
    <p><?=form_error('load[1][grossweight]'); ?></p>
    </td>

 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 <input class="btn btn-success" onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add Item" /></strike>
 <input id="getrates" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="getrate" value="Get Rate" />
 </form>
```

Javascript Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var rowNum = 1;
 function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<tr id="rowNum'+rowNum+'"><td>'+rowNum+'</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="load['+rowNum+'][grossweight]" value="<?=set_value('load[rowNum][grossweight]')?>" placeholder="Gross Weight" ></td></tr>';


    jQuery('#item-row').append(row);

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
```

Codeigniter Controller

```
 // Posted array
 $loads = $this->input->post('load');

if(!empty($loads))
{
    foreach($loads as $id => $data)
    {
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('load['. $id .'][grossweight]', 'Gross Weight', 'required');  

    }
}


if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('air/index', $data);
}
```

Comment: Can't see any submit here .

Comment: i forgotten to copy in the submit button in here, now i just placed in.

Comment: You need to use ajax here. It will handle do form validation without page refresh and your added rows will not disappear then.